# Using both const and non-const for param passing

Tags: c++, constants

Assuming I have a object

```
class Person {
  std::string name;
  // other important fields
  ... 
}
```

Now I want to pass it to a function called updateName

```
void updateName(std::string& mutableName, const Person& person)
```

Is this a valid function? I will pass in like this, for Person instant p:

```
updateName(p.name, p)
```

This looks a bit strange to me, as I am saying I will change the name, but the second param indicates p is const. Obviously I can only pass in a mutable Person instance. The problem is this is in a big system and I can't change the existing interface but add params to it.

Comment: Why isn't this something like `p.updateName(name)`? It seems odd to have an argument referencing a class when this could be a class function. It's also super doubly odd to pass in something you could derive from the object itself, like `p.name` as an argument. This code seems to have been designed inside-out.

Comment: Google's style guide recommends avoiding non-const reference function parameters; it makes the code harder to maintain since it's unclear if a parameter is input or output. Consider passing output parameters via a pointer.

Comment: @rustyx Google's style guide seems great for Google's needs, but it has many problems. In this particular instance, avoiding non-`const` references seem silly to me. If you want a function that mutates an object, it's exactly what you should use. If you don't intend to mutate an object, make it `const`. Seems to me like the a non-`const` reference communicates it's intention pretty clearly. "I will modify this.".

Comment: Yes, except you need to refer to the function declaration to know that. It's invisible at the call site.

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my reply, which talks a bit more about what's expected from `const`.  You may not care about this anymore, but I think it's worth a read (and hopefully I didn't make any false claims this time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may seem odd, but it is fine.  `const Person& person` means that `person` is `const` in `updateName`, it does not mean that the person object you passed to the function is now const.

If `p` were `const` in you calling code then `p.name` wouldn't work as it would have the type `const std::string` and you can't bind a reference to non const to a const object.

---

I do have to question the purpose of providing the object you are modifying along with the field you want to modify.  Just passing the field should be enough since you can't modify the object.

Comment: Yes, passing in the object is convenient if the object has tons of fields (100s) and we want to log some fields selectively.

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld That makes sense then.

Answer (score -3):

The function whose signature is:

```
void updateName(std::string & mutableName, const Person & person);
```

is valid.  However, you risk encountering undefined behavior if `mutableName` is part of `person`.  Consider these examples from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
i = i++ + 1;  // undefined behavior
a[i] = i++;  // undefined behavior
```

The explanation given that they are undefined behavior is that:

```
Modifying an object between two sequence points more than once produces undefined behavior.
```

In the case of your `updateName` function, you may think that one of the arguments get evaluated or passed-in  before the other, but that's not a guarantee at all.

Years ago, I was told that the `const` keyword was a contract between the human programmer and the compiler that the variable would not change.  And here in `updateName()`, we see that this `const` agreement is used with the second argument, so we (the programmers) have a duty to uphold that agreement.

Be aware that there are *sneaky* ways around this `const` agreement that you can find if you try hard enough, but they almost always risk undefined behavior.  One such way, as you have shown, is to pass `p.name` as the first argument, while passing `p` as the second.

If you really want to use  a call like:

```
updateName(p.name, p);
```

then it might be good if you remove the `&` token from the signature, to make it look like this:

```
void updateName(std::string & mutableName, const Person person);
```

That way, a copy of the `Person` is passed in, and changing `mutableName` won't interfere with the `person`.

Or you could consider making both arguments `const &`, and just return the new name, like this:

```
// Will return a newer, better name to use:
std::string updateName(const std::string & name, const Person & person);
```

Now you can use a call like:

```
p.name = updateName(p.name, p);
```

and not have to worry about `p.name`'s change interfering with the behavior of `updateName()`.

---

**EDIT:**

So as commenters have pointed out, apparently the code is *not* undefined after all.  A const reference can still change through other means, even if it's not allowed to be changed directly in the function itself.

I'd like to point out that, while `person` *can* technically change, it won't be obvious to the maintainer(s) maintaining this code.  After all, it *is* declared `const`, and as such some (or most?) knowledgeable maintainers will (incorrectly) assume that its value won't change inside the function.  Not only that, but when they're outside the function call looking at the function call itself, it's not too terribly obvious, either.

I've encountered bugs like these while maintaining code:  A passed-in object (not necessarily `const`) mysteriously has an attribute modified.  "No problem," I think, "I'll just find the line of code that's modifying that attribute, and correct it."  How wrong I was...  Most of a day later spent frustratingly debugging each line step-by-step, I discover that the attribute changes *not when the attribute is assigned to or used*, but *when a completely different line of code is called.*

This leads to strange and difficult-to-find bugs.

I notice that nothing's being returned from your `updateName()` function.  This is a perfect place to return an updated `name`.

Unfortunately, you can't change the existing interface, so you're probably stuck with someone's old decision to modify what's passed in, even if it modifies `person`, which looks like is meant to remain unmodified.

If you truly want to pass in a `person` without risking it being modified, you *can* pass in a copy of `person` with:

```
updateName(p.name, Person(p));
```

`Person(p)` will call the `Person` copy constructor, and leave the original `p` alone.

This is similar to when you call a function that takes a const reference, like this:

```
// Returns double of the input:
int doubler(const int & n)
{
    return n * 2;
}
```

Some people think that you can only pass in integer variables, while integer literals (like `7` and `-12`) are forbidden.

However, you still are allowed to pass in integer literals; the compiler is smart enough to do the right thing here.

So when you said in your post:

```
Obviously I can only pass in a mutable Person instance.
```

I'm not so sure I agree here.  Try passing in `Person(p)` (in place of `p`) and see if that compiles.  Then you can call your `updateName()` function without fear of modifying your `p` object.

(That is, if not modifying `p` is really what you want.)

I hope this helps, and sorry for any confusion caused by the first part of my reply.

Comment: sorry I dont see how your `i = i++ +1;` example is relevant. I dont unstand how the function is supposed to cause undefined behaviour

Comment: Both of the arguments are data members and they are taken by reference. The order of evaluation can't matter.

Comment: just because you have a `const Person&` does not mean that the original object may not get modified trough other means. As simple example, consider `int x = 42; const int& x_ref = x; std::cout << x_ref << " "; x = 0; std::cout << x_ref;` no problem here (prints `42 0`)

Comment: A pointer to `const` and a `const` reference is a contract that you won't use it to change the referred object. Not that the object can never change. You can bind a non-`const` instance to a `const` reference, they don't necessarily refer to unchangeable objects.

Comment: If you can pass `p.name` to a `std::string &` then it is not `const` and doesn't circumvent const correctness.

Comment: @user463035818, I was under the impression that, when you declare an argument to a function as a const reference, then the compiler is free to compile that function as if that argument is unchanging, and take advantage of that fact (for efficiency, etc.).  But there are ways around that, such as getting that function to modify a passed-in argument that (surprisingly or unexpectedly) happens to be part of the first argument.  Why shouldn't this be done?  For the same reason that `i = i++;` or `a[i] = i++;` shouldn't be.  (That is, for the reason given in my post.)

Comment: @J-L what you say is not really wrong (actually I dont understand completely), but consider `void foo( const T& t, T& u)` the compiler is not free to assume that `t` and `u` are never the same object. Hence it cannot do optimizations that would break if `t` and `u` are the same

Comment: `const` here only means that the method cannot(!) modify the object through that reference, and there is no danger to do so, because if you try you will get a compiler error. And thats exaactly what const is for and that is the "contract" you mention. The contract is not "the object referenced by a const reference may not get modified (by other means than the reference)" !

Comment: @J-L This is known as the aliasing problem. Being able to prove that a certain object can never change over a given span of instructions can offer vary powerful opportunities for optimization. But it can be hard to prove. To help compilers, the language imposes rules like the strict aliasing rule and this is one of the reasons why threads must synchronize to manipulate shared data. In this case, it's unsafe to assume `person` doesn't change.

Comment: Wrong answer, disinformation, alternative fact thing.

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my reply, which talks a bit more about what's expected from `const`.  You may not care about this anymore, but I think it's worth a read (and hopefully I didn't make any false claims this time).